# How to use uniq after printf

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I have lot of file which I need to concatenate together with same prefix. I have an idea, but I do not know how to solve this problem:

files:

```
NAME1_C001_xxx.tsv
NAME1_C001_yyy.tsv
NAME2_C001_xxx.tsv
NAME2_C001_yyy.tsv
```

I want to print just uniq prefix - `NAME1 and NAME2`. Length of string in prefix and suffix is vary, but always before prefix is `_C001`

my solution is:

```
fo i in *.tsv

 do prexix=$(printf "%s\n" "${i%_C001*}")

cat $prefix_C001_xxx.tsv $prefix_C001_yyy.tsv > ${i%_C001*}.merged.tsv

done;
```

But this solution is not very good. I have each prefix twice.

Thank you for any help.

**EDITED:**

One solution thanks to anubhava:

```
fo i in $(printf "%s\n" *.tsv | awk -F '_C001' '!seen[$1]++{print $1}')

     do

    cat $prefix_C001_xxx.tsv $prefix_C001_yyy.tsv > ${i%_C001*}.merged.tsv

    done;
```

Comment: What is your expected final file name?

Comment: should be prefix - NAME1.merged.tsv. Something similar to my example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your filenames don't contain any newline you can pipe your list to a `awk` command to print unique prefixes using field separator as `_C001`:

```
printf "%s\n" *.tsv | awk -F '_C001' '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'
NAME1
NAME2
```

You can also use `_` as `FS` in awk:

```
printf "%s\n" *.tsv | awk -F _ '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `printf` at all here; it's just an unnecessary wrapper around the parameter substitution you are already using.

```
for i in *.tsv
do prefix=${i%_C001*}
   [[ -f $prefix.merged.tsv ]] && continue   # Avoid doing the same prefix twice
   cat "${prefix}"_* > "$prefix.merged.tsv"
done
```

Comment: this is very nice solution. Thank you so much.